Is backreference possible with bibtex? Maybe in conjunction with biblatex?
I think, the headline is really the whole question.
The motivation for my question is related with rerun problems.
Bibliography is influenced by second run of a latex compiler
if and only if there are backreferences, I suspect.
I know with biber, the answer is clear.
EDIT:
As I interpret it, the two comments show that I should have asked,
whether a bibliography may be changed by intermediate calls on the latex compiler or auxiliary programs.
The comments below show, that the answer is yes as they give some examples.
Backreferences is only one possibility.

backref package

your comment that the bibliography only changes on  alter run if there are back refs isn't true.  If you are numbering citations by order of use, a \cite in a caption or section heading will appear earlier in the document on a second run when it is picked up by \listoftables etc, which means the bibliography will be re-sorted if you run bibtex after each of the first two runs

if a bibliography entry includes a citation command, you can require additional runs to resolve everything. if you use glossaries and your glossaries include citations, this also requires additional runs. similarly for other external tools. (not sure if that case counts as a second run of the compiler since you also run something else in between.)

The first comment is the answer.. The other comments show, that I asked the wrong question:
I suspected, that bibliography is immutable by latex run or by run of other auxiliary tools. This is wrong.
What I really wanted to ask is on immutability.
And this is answered perfectly by the two comments.
Particularly interesting the case where the latex compiler need not be invoked in between two external tools.
I corrected the Question in an edit.
